# Having Entity Framework trouble

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mef

I'm trying to add a `ProfileProperty` into the `ProfileProperties` table using `ObjectContext.AddObject`.

The `db` fields for the `ProfileProperties` table are:

```
ProfilePropertyID
ProfilePropertyDefinitionID
UserID
PropertyValue
```

The `db` fields for the `ProfilePropertyDefinitions` table are:

```
ProfilePropertyDefinitionID
PropertyName
```

The variables for the `ProfileProperty` object passed in are:

```
ProfilePropertyID
ProfilePropertyDefinition
User
PropertyValue
```

The `ProfilePropertyDefinitionID` and `UserID` both are foreign keys, so after creating the `ProfileProperty` object I select the `User` and the `ProfilePropertyDefinition` from their tables to fill the `ProfileProperty` with the related objects.

Then, when I try to `AddObject`, passing in an object with those variables I get an error:

> InnerException = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PropertyName', table 'mydbserver.dbo.ProfilePropertyDefinitions'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

I did a break to check to see what the object I passed in was holding and it has this:

```
ProfilePropertyID = -1
ProfilePropertyDefinition = 
    { ProfilePropertyDefinitionID = 3
      PropertyName = "First Name" }
User = /*Not going  to put details here, but assume the user object is there*/
PropertyValue = "Matt"
```

#### Questions

1. Why is saying that the `PropertyName` is null when it's there?
2. Why is it trying to add the `ProfilePropertyDefinition` object into the `ProfilePropertyDefinitions` table in the first place? (I don't want it to add or update related objects)

#### Service Layer `AddProfile()`

```
public int AddProfile(ProfilePropertyViewModel property)
{
    int objId = -1;
    ProfileProperty profile = null;

    if (ValidateProfile(property))
    {
        try
        {
            using (DbTransaction transaction = _profileRepository.BeginTransaction())
            {
                profile = ProfilePropertyTranslator.ViewToDomain(property);
                profile.User = _userRepository.SelectByKey(UserColumns.UserName, property.UserName);
                profile.ProfilePropertyDefinitionReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("GraffytysDBEntities.ProfilePropertyDefinition", "ProfilePropertyDefinitionID", property.ProfilePropertyDefinitionID);

                _profileRepository.Add(profile);
                if (_profileRepository.Save() >= 0)
                {
                   transaction.Commit();
                   objId = property.ProfilePropertyId;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    return objId;
 }
```

#### Repository `Add()`:

```
    public void Add(E entity)
    {
        _ctx.AddObject(entity.GetType().Name, entity);
    }
```

Comment: So you're creating a new `ProfileProperty` with an existing `User` and `ProfilePropertyDefinition`. Do you select the existing objects from the same context you're calling `AddObject` on?

Comment: You could try to change code and set `ProfilePropertyDefinitionReference.EntityKey` and `UserReference.EntityKey`. You won't have to select it first from db and it will propably solve your problem.

Comment: @LukLed, can you give an example of that in an answer (so it can be voted/accepted)?

Comment: Yes they are all from the same context.

Comment: What does ProfilePropertyTranslator.ViewToDomain(property) do?

Comment: Takes a ProfilePropertyViewModel and creates a new ProfileProperty object using it's content. The ViewModel is a flat version (doesn't contain related objects) of the DomainModel version - ProfileProperty

Comment: Try using the same function, but don't use ProfilePropertyViewModel and ProfilePropertyTranslator, just create ProfileProperty by hand and check if it works. Take sample User and ProfileProperty values.

Comment: I've put a break point right after the translator to check to see that the object was created correctly. All it does is take values and create an object from it, the exact same as if I did new ProfileProperty(/* my values here */)

Comment: Just write the simplest function that adds ProfileProperty. Don't use ProfilePropertyViewModel, don't use ProfilePropertyTranslator. Does it work?

Comment: Yes it does! I had a mistake in my Translator, it create a new ProfilePropertyDefinition object just to fill it's spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will propably solve your problem and is more efficient way to set foreign key properties:

```
profileProperty.ProfilePropertyDefinitionReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("MyEntities.ProfilePropertyDefinitions", "ProfilePropertyDefinitionID", 3);
```

You have to replace 'MyEntities' with your db model name.

You could also check if you are adding `ProfilePropertyDefinition` to your `ObjectContext` somewhere else in the code. It could be the problem, not this part of the code.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not adding anything else using the same `ObjectContext`? You may be adding another `ProfilePropertyDefinition` to the same `ObjectContext` and it throws an error. Check it before calling SaveChanges. Check if `ProfilePropertyDefinitions` contain new rows.

Comment: It shouldn't be... I just checked and there are no new rows. Here's the code at the place I call the add to the repository: _profileRepository.Add(property); if(_profileRepository.Save() >= 0) { transaction.Commit(); }

Comment: OK. Could you paste whole code? You could also look at SQL profiler and see what sql is actually called. Remember that you don't have to call `_repository.Add(...)` to insert object to `ObjectContext`. If new object is connected to another object that you added to `ObjectContext` by `_repository.Add(...)`, it will be added too.